# Cron job to invoke a jar for multiple input parameter files

Tags: shell, parameters, cron

I have few huge input files which need to be passed as a parameter to an executable jar and configure the processing via a CRON job.

Example: Consider a.txt, b.txt, c.txt are my input files:
Currently, I am executing below commands :
`nohup java -jar fileprocessor.jar a.txt &`
`nohup java -jar fileprocessor.jar b.txt &`
`nohup java -jar fileprocessor.jar c.txt &`

The fileprocessor.jar will process a.txt, b.txt, c.txt input files simultaneously and end up generating corresponding a_output.txt, b_output.txt, b_output.txt files.

I am trying to configure a CRON job which triggers the jar file for each input file.

Thanks in advance for your response

Comment: Welcome to SO, please read about asking [Minimal Complete & Verifiable Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). What have you tried so far? Also, how frequently/when do you want those jobs to run? Once a week? Twice a month? Every other Tuesday at 3am?

Comment: I tried the below code which will run the cron job every day:0 0 * * * java -jar /home/mydir/fileprocessor.jar a.txt &